# Convert string to boolean with Pentaho Kettle

Tags: oracle, mongodb, pentaho

I'm moving an Oracle db to a Mongo DB, using Pentaho Kettle. I've succeded in doing almost everything I wanted, but I just have a last problem.

In the oracle db, they have a field that have two states : Y or N, instead of a nice boolean *true* and *false*. I wanted to make a mapping in the transformation to say that Y is *true* and N is *false*, but Pentaho translates this as strings, and not like real *true* and *false*.

Do I have an easy way to set up my booleans?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with MongoDB, or Pentaho, or any of that. With that said: if you are converting from Oracle to something else, and that something else has the BOOLEAN data type (which Oracle does not), it seems that you will need to write something like a CASE expression on the receiving side. Something like: If the existing Y/N column is named "flag", then import `case when flag = 'Y' then true else false end` (this assumes the receiving end understands `true` and `false` as Boolean constants).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You change the type with the `Select values` step, on the `Meta-data` panel.

And it works !

However, as the string representation of boolean in PDI is Y/N as well as true/false depending on the context, the guilty step may be the `Mongo DB Output`.

Right-click on the Oracle `Table Input`, select `output field` and check the type of your field. if it is not boolean, convert it with the `Select value`.

Then right-click on the `Mongo DB Output`, select `input field` and check the type of your field. If it is boolean, then it gets silently converted to Y/N. In that case, use a `Replace in string` step and convert Y/N to "true"/"false" as strings and let Mongo DB silently convert these special string to boolean.

Comment: you have to enable the 'Extra attribute [SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE]' and /or 'supports boolean data type' in the database configuration. click edit and than 'Feature List'